# Clear the cache in memcached server on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, osx-lion

I'm running Ruby on Rails 3.0.6 on OS X Lion.  I had setup a memcached server instance and was caching in development for testing purposes.  Everything was working fine, but I decided to clear out my database and see how the application ran without any data.  I cleared it out, restarted Apache, and turned off caching in development mode.  Went to the home page, and it appeared the data was cached still, so I restarted Apache, but that had no effect (keep in mind, there is no data in the database).  Then I killed the memcached process (which restarted itself).  That didn't work.  So I shutdown my machine, and started it back up, and still, the data is cached.

Is there a way to flush this cache?  If it's stored in memory, why wouldn't a reboot clear the cache?

Comment: you can use `clear` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemCacheStore.html to flush the cache.  As far as I know, memcached is a persistent cache storage solution so a reboot won't clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out deleting the cache folder in /tmp/cache cleared the cache.  Now I know :)

Comment: which means you have filestore as your cache store and not memcached

Answer (score 7):

Or you can do it from CLI:

```
echo 'flush_all' | nc localhost 11211
```

*Source*: [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-flush-contents-of-memcached-instance/)